# Using a Dictionary in a TreeNode Tag - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, treenode

I'm writing a bit of code that I want to populate a TreeView, which it does quite successfully, but I also want to put a Dictionary in the Tag of each Level 1 child node. Once the Tag has been set to the Dictionary, is there any way I can modify the dictionary, without redeclaring the Tag.

```
For Each verse In Verses

    Dim _verse = verse.ToString.Trim
    Dim _node As TreeNode = New TreeNode(_verse.Split(vbNewLine).First & "...")
    _node.ToolTipText = _verse
    _node.Tag = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Node.Nodes.Add(_node)

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can later just cast the tag of the not to `Dictionary(Of String, Object)` and then manipulate the dictionary as usual.

For example, assuming that `currentNode` is the node of interest, you can have something like the following.

```
Dim dictionary as Dictionary(Of String, Object) = _
    CType(currentNode.Tag, Dictionary(Of String, Object))

dictionary.Add("NewKey", newObject);
```

Comment: That means that you have not assigned the dictionary instance to the Tag. Use the debugger to check the value of the Tag and see what the actual type is of the object assigned to the Tag.